# pyspark fillna is not working on column of ArrayType

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark cluster version 3.1.2. I have following input data

```
+-------+------+------------+
|   name|gender|         arr|
+-------+------+------------+
|  James|     M|     [60000]|
|Michael|     M| [70000, 31]|
| Robert|  null|[44, 400000]|
|  Maria|     F|[500000, 12]|
|    Jen|      |        null|
+-------+------+------------+
```

I have to remove null values from the all columns. "gender" column is StringType while "arr" column is of ArrayType. Some values are null is both columns. When I apply fillna function, values are remove from gender column but not from arr column. Have a look at output

```
>>> df.fillna("").show()
+-------+------+------------+
|   name|gender|         arr|
+-------+------+------------+
|  James|     M|     [60000]|
|Michael|     M| [70000, 31]|
| Robert|      |[44, 400000]|
|  Maria|     F|[500000, 12]|
|    Jen|      |        null|
+-------+------+------------+
```

Same happens if I use na.drop or na.fill functions. Where is the problem ? How can I remove null from arr column

Answer (score 7):

`fillna` only supports `int, float, string, bool` datatypes, columns with other datatypes are ignored.

> For example, if value is a string, and subset contains a non-string column, then the non-string column is simply ignored.[(doc)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna.html?highlight=fillna)

You can replace `null` values in array columns using `when and otherwise` constructs.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
default_value = F.array().cast("array<int>")
fill_rule = F.when(F.col('arr').isNull(),default_value).otherwise(F.col('arr'))
df.withColumn('arr', fill_rule).show()
```