# pyspark - How to define MapType for when/otherwise

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark

I have a pyspark DataFrame with a *MapType* column that either contains the *map<string, int>* format or is *None*.

I need to perform some calculations using `collect_list`. But `collect_list` excludes `None` values and I am trying to find a workaround, by transforming *None* to string similar to [Include null values in collect_list in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57135151/include-null-values-in-collect-list-in-pyspark)

However, on my case I can't use `df.na.fill` with subset, since `fillna` only supports *int, float, string, bool datatypes*, columns with other datatypes are ignored. The solution proposed in [pyspark fillna is not working on column of ArrayType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69477151/pyspark-fillna-is-not-working-on-column-of-arraytype) somehow doesn't work for my case, since I get a type mismatch error.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
default_value = F.lit('none')
fill_rule = F.when(F.col('map_values').isNull(), default_value).otherwise(F.col('map_values'))
df.withColumn('map_new', fill_rule)
```

I understand I should change the `default_value` format, with `.cast('map<string,int>')`, but I don't know how to define it.
I would like to get with something like {'none':1}.

I am new to pyspark, so maybe there is a more efficient way to achieve what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can create `MapType` using `create_map` of required literals.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,2,{'abc':12}),(3,4,None)],['c1','c2','c3'])
df.show()
+---+---+-----------+
| c1| c2|         c3|
+---+---+-----------+
|  1|  2|[abc -> 12]|
|  3|  4|       null|
+---+---+-----------+

from pyspark.sql import functions as f

defaultval = f.create_map(f.lit('None'),f.lit(1))
df = df.withColumn('c3',f.when(f.col('c3').isNull(),defaultval).otherwise(f.col('c3'))
df.select(f.collect_list('c3')).show(truncate=False)
+--------------------------+
|collect_list(c3)          |
+--------------------------+
|[[abc -> 12], [None -> 1]]|
+--------------------------+
```