# Forward filling pyspark dataframe based on previous values

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two spark dataframes which will be full outer joined.

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([[1,5,[1,2]],[1,15,[1,3]],[2,4,[3,4]]], 
                             columns=["id","day","state"]))
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame([[1,10,[5,6]],[1,12,[7]],[2,4,[3]],
                            [2,6,[10,12]],[2,10,[8,9]]], columns=["id","day","action"]))
df1.join(df2, on=["id","day"], how="fullouter").orderBy("id","day").show()
```

The resulting output is shown below

```
+---+---+------+--------+
| id|day| state|  action|
+---+---+------+--------+
|  1|  5|[1, 2]|    null|
|  1| 10|  null|  [5, 6]|
|  1| 12|  null|     [7]|
|  1| 15|[1, 3]|    null|
|  2|  4|[3, 4]|     [3]|
|  2|  6|  null|[10, 12]|
|  2| 10|  null|  [8, 9]|
+---+---+------+--------+
```

I need the output to look like what's shown below, i.e. the last state within the same id needs to be copied down.  And the null actions replaced by `[0]`.  Both these dataframes are very large.

```
+---+---+------+--------+
| id|day| state|  action|
+---+---+------+--------+
|  1|  5|[1, 2]|     [0]|
|  1| 10|[1, 2]|  [5, 6]|
|  1| 12|[1, 2]|     [7]|
|  1| 15|[1, 3]|     [0]|
|  2|  4|[3, 4]|     [3]|
|  2|  6|[3, 4]|[10, 12]|
|  2| 10|[3, 4]|  [8, 9]|
+---+---+------+--------+
```

Comment: You want to look into https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna and specifically `ffill` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html

Comment: What is the logic on how you populated the `null` values in `state`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Pyspark's [`last`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.last.html) function to retrieve the last value within a window; `ignorenulls=True` is a needed argument to retrieve the last *non-null* value.
To fill NA in the array column, instead, we need to use the same method proposed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69477151/pyspark-fillna-is-not-working-on-column-of-arraytype) since `.fillna` does not support arrays.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# window to determine last value
w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('day').rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

# `df` is your outer-joined dataframe
(df
 .withColumn('state', F.last('state', ignorenulls=True).over(w))
 .withColumn('action', F.when(F.col('action').isNull(), F.array(F.lit(0))).otherwise(F.col('action')))
).show()

+---+---+------+--------+
| id|day| state|  action|
+---+---+------+--------+
|  1|  5|[1, 2]|     [0]|
|  1| 10|[1, 2]|  [5, 6]|
|  1| 12|[1, 2]|     [7]|
|  1| 15|[1, 3]|     [0]|
|  2|  4|[3, 4]|     [3]|
|  2|  6|[3, 4]|[10, 12]|
|  2| 10|[3, 4]|  [8, 9]|
+---+---+------+--------+
```

Comment: good one ........